# Adding Items Using DataBinding from TreeView to ListBox WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox, treeview

I want to add the selected item from the `TreeView` to the `ListBox` control using `DataBinding` (If it can work with `DataBinding`).

```
<TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Margin="30,32,0,83" 
          Name="treeView1" 
          Width="133" >

</TreeView>
<ListBox VerticalAlignment="Top" 
         Margin="208,36,93,0" 
         Name="listBox1" 
         Height="196" >       
</ListBox>
```

`TreeView` is populated from the code behind page with some dummy data.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to an element using ElementName, so if you wanted to bind the selected tree item to the ItemsSource of a ListBox:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=treeView1}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it is possible, since WPF is really flexible with data binding, but I haven't done that specific scenario yet.

I've been following a [WPF Databinding FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2006/10/19/wpf-basic-data-binding-faq.aspx) from the MSDN blogs as of late and it provides a lot of insights that might help.